# PHP Session Hijacking Detected

Tags: php, security, session, session-hijacking

I have this code:

```
if (isset( $_SESSION['user_agent'] )) {
    if ($_SESSION['user_agent'] != md5( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] )) {
        die('Session error.');
    }   
}
```

Everything works fine. But every time I login (once per 24 hours), I get the error. Is the user agent changing or something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your session might expire

Comment: Are you sure that error is not shown at any other point in your code? What happens if `$_SESSION['user_agent']` is not set?

Comment: Thanks for the response, although the error would only show **if** the session is set.

Comment: Chrome I've heard updates in the background and the user agent string changes as well.

Comment: @Jack it gets set. I just removed that part for simplicity.

Comment: If this happens every time, I would suggest simply debugging the actual user agent values and see why they changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions have a limited lifetime http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php usually minutes or some hours

Comment: Thanks for the response, although the error would only show **if** the session is set.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone capable of hijacking sessions (i.e. via sniffing unencrypted HTTP) has the keys to the kingdom once an authenticated user comes along.

`HTTP_USER_AGENT`? Yeah, that's also sent in the clear, and the attacker can just spoof it. Any MitM applicance that steals/spoofs session cookies will generally also impersonate the user agent of the user's browser too.

The only solution here is HTTPS, which is now free thanks to [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org).